# How to correctly cite a bibliographic source?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf

I've a problem during the citation bibliographic source.

```
%In the bibliography file:
@article{MER,
    Title = {Mars Exploration Rover Engineering Cameras},
    Author = {J. N. Maki,J. F. Bell III, K. E. Herkenhoff, S. W. Squyres, A. Kiely, M. Klimesh, M. Schwochert, T. Litwin, R. Willson, A. Johnson, M. Maimone, E. Baumgartner, A. Collins, M. Wadsworth, S. T. Elliot, A. Dingizian, D. Brown, E. C. Hagerott, L. Scherr, R. Deen, D. Alexander, J. Lorre},
    Journal = {Journal of Geophysical Research},
    Year = 2003,
    Volume = 108
}

%In the .tex file
Cameras selected for this work have been taken from NASA’s MER (Mars Exploration Rover) mission \cite{MER}
```

After compiling I've the following warning:
CItation "MER" on page 15 undefined on input line 594.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the `author` field: The separator between authors is not `,` ("comma") but the keyword `and`. Hence, you need to rewrite the field as

```
Author = {J. N. Maki and Bell, III, J. F. and K. E. Herkenhoff and S. W. Squyres 
  and A. Kiely and M. Klimesh and M. Schwochert and T. Litwin and R. Willson 
  and A. Johnson and M. Maimone and E. Baumgartner and A. Collins and M. Wadsworth 
  and S. T. Elliot and A. Dingizian and D. Brown and E. C. Hagerott and L. Scherr 
  and R. Deen and D. Alexander and J. Lorre},
```

Ditto for all other entries.

Incidentally, do observe that I changed `J. F. Bell III` to `Bell, III, J. F.`; in particular, observe the use of commas *within* a given author's name. This change is necessary to help BibTeX parse the components of the full name into given name, surname, and "Junior" components.

---

*Addendum*: You didn't state *how* you tried to create the bibliography, but the screenshot you posted suggests that you use `biblatex` and `biber`. The log file generated by biber (contained in the file `\jobname.blg`) contains the following information:

```
[273] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - Name "J. N. Maki,J. F. Bell III, K. E. Herkenhoff, 
S. W. Squyres, A. Kiely, M. Klimesh, M. Schwochert, T. Litwin, R. Willson, 
A. Johnson, M. Maimone, E. Baumgartner, A. Collins, M. Wadsworth, 
S. T. Elliot, A. Dingizian, D. Brown, E. C. Hagerott, L. Scherr, R. Deen, 
D. Alexander, J. Lorre" has too many commas, skipping entry 'MER'
[273] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry with key 'MER' in section '0' is cited 
and found but not created (likely due to sourcemap)
```

Note the part

```
Name ... has too many commas, skipping entry 'MER'.
```

Since no entry corresponding to the `MER` key is created, the citation call-out just reports the input argument, viz., **MER**.

BibTeX would issue a similar, "too many commas", error message.